# Maximum Depth of N-ary Tree when use BFS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, tree, breadth-first-search

For get the max depth of a nary-tree, this code below is a correct answer.

```
var maxDepth = function(root) {
 if (!root) {
    return 0
 }
 let depth = 0;
 let arr=[root];

 while (arr.length) {
    let arrlength=arr.length;
    for (let i=0;i<arrlength;i++) {
        let curr=arr.shift();
        arr.push(...curr.children);           
    }
    depth++;
 }
 return depth;

};
```

However, if I use arr.length in the for loop instead of use "let arrlength=arr.length;" and use arrlength, it will be a wrong answer...
May I know why? I can't tell any difference. Thank you so much!

```
var maxDepth = function(root) {
 if (!root) {
    return 0
 }
 let depth = 0;
 let arr=[root];

 while (arr.length) {       
    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        let curr=arr.shift();
        arr.push(...curr.children);           
    }
    depth++;
 }
 return depth;

};
```

can be tested here:
https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-n-ary-tree/

Comment: `arr.shift()` changes the length of the array.

Comment: This is breath first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let curr = arr.shift()` removes the first element from the array and assigns it to `curr`.

`arr.push(...curr.children)` adds all the children to the end of the array.

Both of these operations change the array length, and the test `i < arr.length` uses the current length each time through. But the loop is only supposed to process the original array elements. `arrlength` contains the array's original length before the loop. It won't change as the array is modified, so the loop will operate the correct number of times.

You could use `.length` in the loop if you made a copy of `arr` before the loop, and looped over that rather than modifying the array you're looping over.

```js
var maxDepth = function(root) {
  if (!root) {
    return 0
  }
  let depth = 0;
  let arr = [root];

  while (arr.length) {
    let copy = [...arr];
    arr.splice(0, arr.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
      let curr = copy[i];
      arr.push(...curr.children);
    }
    depth++;
  }
  return depth;

};

const tree = {
  value: 1,
  children: [{
      value: 3,
      children: [{
        value: 5,
        children: []
      }, {
        value: 6,
        children: []
      }]
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      children: []
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      children: []
    }
  ]
};

console.log(maxDepth(tree));
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I was so confused haha! So we need this to store the original length, since each iteration in the for loop after we push/shift, the length of the array changed, if we don't use a variable to store that, the for loop will compare i with the new length everytime right? :D Thank you so much!!